# Nested objects searching in angular Material table - filter predicate

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a reusable angular material table using ngFor.
It is working very well.
But I am looking for a solution where I can search for the nested data as well.
Currently I am able to search non nested objects/values.
Now I want to be able to seach for the nested data searching as well which is being printing in the table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide the basic code that you wrote.

Comment: Basic code is same as angular material ngfor code available at angular material website.